# What is the grammar of ‘quid illud quod’ in Ambrose De. ob. Val. 35?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, grammar-identification, interrogative, relative-clause

## Introduction and question

Ambrose is generally not too hard to read; his structure is pretty straight forward, his word-choice is not too weird, and he seems to have favoured a style which would be easily understood by his congregation, which after all was *not* made up of the one-percenters of the one per cent. (Of course, as most of us, I am reading an English translation, then consult interesting passages in the Latin, then do my own translations back to English). One phrase I encountered today proved to be more difficult than anticipated, though:

> **Latin:**
> *Quid illud quod morī nōn timuit? Immō prō omnibus sē obtulit dīcēns quod frūstrā propter sē aliī perīclitārentur: sibīque potius mortem optābat, nē ipse aliīs causa mortis esset.*

> **Very verbatim:**
> What/Which that which he did not fear to die? Quite the opposite: For everyone himself he offered, saying that for no purpose because of / by means of / through himself others were put in danger: and for himself instead/rather death he chose, not himself for others to have been the cause of death.

> **Normal English:**
> What/Which [thing? -> fact?] that he did not fear to die? Quite the opposite: He offered himself for everyone, saying that for no purpose others were put in danger because of himself: and for himself he rather chose death, for fear that he himself would have been the cause of death for others.

In [Conloqvivm](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58781775#58781775), Joonas said that:

> For the lack of a better word, *quid illud quod* might be better treated as a “phrasal cluster”. Much like the French *qu’est-ce que il y a* should not be analyzed as “what is it that it has there” but “what is it”.

My follow-up question, which is the question at hand here, is simply this:
**What exactly is going on grammatically then?**

I was from this encouraged to ask this publicly, as it seems to pose grammatical challenges which ‘deserves proper analysis in front of all eyes.’

## Other translations

Liebeschuetz and Hill suggest ‘What of the fact that Valentinian was not afraid to die?’ But I am unable to understand how they get ‘of the fact’. Joonas said that ‘Literally it seems to be *quid [est]* illud quod*, a relatively simple relative clause, but understanding and translating (in that order!) *quid* and *quod* well† is hard.’

## Remarks

* I have noticed that Ambrose seems to not bother with forms of *esse*; I have encountered at least one instance of accusative with infinitive, where there was no (intransitive) verb. As far as I know, this was common, but it should be worth noting; also, I have heard this is not uncommon in other heavily inflected languages, such as Russian, ɔ: the verb *to be* is not important to utter for a sentence to carry proper meaning. E.g.:

- Asked to a male, informal: Ты голодный? – [Are] you hungry?
- Asked to a male, formal:
  Вы голодный? – [Are] you hungry?

My Russian friend whom I asked for these sentences, said that it was actually hard to figure out how the verb would be in these sentences, which I would dare say perfectly illustrates the point.

† It is interesting how *not* having ‘well’ surrounded by commas, changed the meaning of that sentence from Joonas up there.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that *illud* might be translated as *that*, referring to the subordinate clause introduced by *quod*, which might also be translated as *that*:

> *Quid illud **quod mori non timuit***?
>
> What [is] that **that he didn't fear dying**?

This use of *illud* is described by [Allen and Greenough](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/demonstrative-pronouns):

> e. The pronouns *hīc*, *ille*, and *is* are used to point in either
> direction, back to something just mentioned or forward to something
> about to be mentioned.
>
> f. The neuter forms often refer to a clause, phrase, or idea.

They also mention [this particular use](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/indicative-quod) of *quod*:

> 572. A peculiar form of substantive clause consists of *quod* (in the sense of *that*, *the fact that*) with the indicative. The clause in
>      the indicative with *quod* is used when the statement is regarded as a
>      fact.

This is also consistent with the translation you provided by Liebeschuetz and Hill, in which *illud quod* would be translated as *the fact that*:

> What of the fact **that Valentinian was not afraid to die**?

Comment: I think you nailed it. Using your explanation, I was able to find the relevant explanation in my grammar: Eitrem § 175 Explicative quod, stating that ‘*Quod* with indicative describes **the circumstance that** or **the fact that**. *Quod* really is the relative neuter pronoun and is used almost like an inner object (as per § 66): ‘on account of which’, ‘considering which, that’. If the sentence includes a reason, we get *quod* as causal conjunction  (§ 180.2).

Comment: @Expedito Bipes: Does "quid illud quod mori non timuit?" = "What is it that he didn't fear dying?". A blunt way of saying: "What is this phenomenon that..."

Comment: FYI, I wrote about this endeavour on my blog, and how it is addressed in the Norwegian Latin grammar: https://cannedman.blogspot.com/2021/08/lingua-latina-quid-illud-quod-mori-non.html. I do reference your answer with link and user name.